# why is negation before the quantifier and not Property?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I am studying square of opposition. **Some dogs have fleas** is shown in the text as (see *bottom left* sentence in image)

$\neg \forall x [D_{x} \supset \neg F_{x}]$

Why is it not (notice the negation changed) ?

$\forall x [\neg D_{x} \supset \neg F_{x}]$

```
Reason 1
```

Reason I say so is because the second option translates into English pretty well:
"Some dogs have fleas" is equivalent to "Not all dogs have not fleas" which is equivalent to "For all X, **if** x is *not* dog **then** x has *not* fleas" which is what the 2nd option says

As a quick reference, See Tidman mentions english translation in 7.3 that $\forall x [D_{x} \supset F_{x}]$ translates "For all x , **if** x is a dog **then** it has fleas"

```
Reason 2
```

Secondly $\neg \forall x$ translates into something funny like "For all not x" and messes with the idea of "universe of discourse"

Tidman Page 180:
[image: Tidman Page 180]

Comment: $\lnot\forall x(Dx\supset\lnot Fx)$ means "Not all dogs have no fleas", while $\forall x(\lnot Dx\supset \lnot Fx)$ means "All non-dogs have no fleas".

Comment: @Rahul great answer !

Answer (score 6):

Because "Some dogs have fleas" is the same as "Not all dogs have no fleas".

The last one is symbolized with : $\lnot \forall x (Dog(x) \to \lnot Fleas(x))$.

This in turn is equivalent to : $\exists x (Dog(x) \land Fleas(x))$, which is the equivalent symbolization of "Some dogs have fleas".

---

Your proposed symbolization :  $\forall x (\lnot Dog(x) \to \lnot Fleas(x))$ means that : "Every object in the universe, if it is **not** a dog, it has **no** fleas", which means : "Every object in the universe, if it has fleas, then it is a dog", and this is not the same as "Some dogs have fleas".

---

$¬∀x$ does **not**  translate into something funny like "For all not x" but in "Not for all x", i.e. into "Some x not".

Comment: Mauro.Nice answer.

Comment: Mauro.If it has no flees, then it is a dog!! :) Happy New Year.

Answer (score 1):

Think about it like this:
\begin{align*}
&\textsf{Some dogs have fleas.} \\
&\iff \textsf{It is not the case that (all dogs do not have fleas).} \\
&\iff \textsf{It is not the case that (for all $x$, if $x$ is a dog, then $x$ does not have fleas).} \\
&\iff \textsf{It is not the case that ($\forall x~ [D(x) \supset {\sim} F(x)]$).} \\
&\iff {\sim} (\forall x ~ [D(x) \supset {\sim} F(x)]) \\
\end{align*}