# MUST an I and O proposition simultaneously be be true?

Tags: predicate-logic

In the [Square of Opposition](http://www.uky.edu/~rosdatte/phi120/lesson14a.htm), MUST I and O proposition "simultaneously be be true" ? The webpage is silent on it.

I think it "COULD be true" as in the [square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3495869/why-is-negation-before-the-quantifier-and-not-property) but **not** a "MUST be true". Can someone show me **both** a Venn diagram and predicate languages (i.e. with $\forall$ and $\exists$ )

Answer (score 1):

The correct reading is "could" and not "must". The linked page has: "not both false".

See [The Traditional Square of Opposition](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/square/).

The rules are :

> Two propositions are contradictory iff they cannot both be true and they cannot both be false [A-O and E-I].
>
> Two propositions are contraries iff they cannot both be true but can both be false [A-E].
>
> Two propositions are subcontraries iff they **cannot** [not possible] both be false but **can** both be true [O-I].

"Can be both true": consider the following example : "Some natural number is Even" [I] and "Some natural number is **not** Even" [O].

"Cannot both be false" means that we have no interpretation where neither the predicate nor its negation apply.

Assuming [bivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_bivalence), a number is Even or not; thus it is not possible that "Some natural number is Even" [I] and "Some natural number is **not** Even" [O] are both False.

Can they be one True and one False ? YES, they can.

Consider again the natural numbers starting from zero: "Some natural number is greater-or-equal to zero" is True while "Some natural number is **not** greater-or-equal (i.e. is less than) to zero" is False.

---

Nitpicking comment: Aristotle was also the inventor of [Modal logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/#SylMod): "can" means *possibility* and "must" mean *necessity*.

The relation between the two is :

> “necessarily P” is equivalent to “not possibly not P” and “possibly P” to “not necessarily not P”.

Comment: are you saying simultaneously they **MUST** be true. I think this is incorrect. Simultaneously they **could** be true. Which is why I asked for proof.

Comment: I get what you are saying, However I am trying to draw a distinction between "Are I and O simultaneously **must** be true" OR  "Are I and O simultaneously **could** be true". I agree, the answer to 2nd question is true (same like your examples) but if the answer to question 1 is also true, then how come it is not mentioned in anybook etc..